# Javascript functionality reloads again if I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-request

On my webpage I am achieving most of the functionality using JS like saving the record using ajax request etc. My scenario is like when I click on Update/Save Changes button and Ajax Request or other Javascript functions are invoked. After performing the operations if I refresh the page or reload it the whole code is run again and data is again saved in the database. Can you please give me a solution of how to stop this from being done.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: youe code is completely javascript or it involves asp.net postback ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some indicator that the script should not run.

For example if you have the following scenario:

`Page is loaded -> JS runs with AJAX -> data is saved to DB`

You will need to add the indicator:

`Page is loaded -> JS to check if it should run -> JS runs with AJAX or stop`

You can generate this indicator from the server side or save it on the client via cookies, localStorage, IndexedDB or anything else you would like.